# redis installation echoing variables to bash is not working ubuntu 14.04

Tags: redis, ubuntu-14.04

I downloaded redis in /usr/local/src/

Code:

```
cd redis-3.0.6
me@ubuntu:sudo make
me@ubuntu:sudo make PREFIX=/usr/local/redis-3.0.6 install
me@ubuntu:sudo ln -s redis-3.0.6 /usr/local/redis
me@ubuntu:echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/redis/bin:$PATH' >> -/.bash_profile

me@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/redis-3.0.6$ echo 'export
PATH=/usr/local/redis/bin:$PATH' >> -/.bash_profile
bash: -/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Use ~ (tilde) not - (hyphen).

Comment: did that it work now